# "TPM Storage is not available" and other TPM issues

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803, tpm

Three days ago I completely reinstalled Windows, including formatting my drives. 
 Two days ago I installed the Windows Cumulative Update, [KB4338819](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4338819/windows-10-update-kb4338819).  After doing so, I got a TPM reset request on boot.  I eventually did so, but Windows still reported an error.  Here is the TPM log from that day:

> **2018-07-12 - TPMinformation.txt**
>
> ```
> TPM Device Information
>
>   -TPM Present: True
>   -TPM Version: 2.0
>   -TPM Manufacturer ID: INTC
>   -TPM Manufacturer Version: 11.0.0.0
>   -PPI Spec Version: 1.2
>   -Ready For Storage: False
>   -Ready For Attestation: False
>   -Information Flags: 0x0000000E
>   -Is Capable For Attestation: False
>   -Clear Needed To Recover: True
>   -TPM Has Vulnerable FW: False
>   -PCR7 Binding State: 0
>   -TPM Spec Version 0
>   -TPM Errata Date: 
>   -PC Client Version: 0
> ```

That is when I originally posted this question.  The following day Windows reported that Attestation was available but Storage was still not.  Today both showed available.  Here is the log from earlier this morning:

> **2018-07-14 9:00 AM - TPMInformation.txt**
>
> ```
> TPM Device Information
>
>   -TPM Present: True
>   -TPM Version: 2.0
>   -TPM Manufacturer ID: INTC
>   -TPM Manufacturer Version: 11.0.0.1180
>   -PPI Spec Version: 1.2
>   -Ready For Storage: True
>   -Ready For Attestation: True
>   -Information Flags: 0x00000000
>   -Is Capable For Attestation: True
>   -Clear Needed To Recover: False
>   -TPM Has Vulnerable FW: False
>   -PCR7 Binding State: 2
>   -TPM Spec Version 116
>   -TPM Errata Date: Thursday, October 30, 2014
>   -PC Client Version: 256
> ```

Between those two logs I had installed nothing and not performed any reboot.  It seemingly fixed itself.  Then, about 20 minutes ago I noticed in Device Manager that I had an unknown device.  I ran the troubleshooter and it said "Unkonwn USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed) has error".  I believe this is my bluetooth (I have no bluetooth currently).  So I did the automatic fix. It requested a reboot.  After the reboot, I had the TPM errors again! I exported a new log file:

> **2018-07-14 9:30 AM - TPMInformation.txt**
>
> ```
> TPM Device Information
>
>   -TPM Present: True
>   -TPM Version: 2.0
>   -TPM Manufacturer ID: INTC
>   -TPM Manufacturer Version: 11.0.0.0
>   -PPI Spec Version: 1.2
>   -Ready For Storage: False
>   -Ready For Attestation: False
>   -Information Flags: 0x0000000E
>   -Is Capable For Attestation: False
>   -Clear Needed To Recover: True
>   -TPM Has Vulnerable FW: False
>   -PCR7 Binding State: 0
>   -TPM Spec Version 0
>   -TPM Errata Date: 
>   -PC Client Version: 0
> ```

So my new question is... WTF?

Is my motherboard failing?

ASUS Strix (GL502VY). Bios version 203.

Comment: This could have a vendor specific solution, what is the make/mode of your laptop?

Comment: ASUS Strix (GL502VY). Bios version 203.  Added to post. Thanks.

Comment: Also when I first posted I had BIOS revision 202. I updated and the problem persists.

Comment: The TPM is the "trusted platform module". If you are not using bitlocker and don't know what it is, just disable it (it sounds like it might be damaged). TPM is used to securely checksum the state of parts of the system at boot up which can only be read, and can be used to ensure the boot process is not tampered with.

Comment: How do I disable it? I didn't see anything in the BIOS.  And shouldn't I worry about something like this being "damaged"?  Since it persisted across OS installations I assume it's a hardware level failure?

Comment: Yesterday when I turned on my laptop the Security Processor section no longer showed a warning.  When drilling down, it still said the Attestation was not available but that the storage was working.  Today when I unlocked it (no reboots, mind you) it said both are available.  So... it fixed itself...

Comment: Completely rewrote the question due to new developments...